# LuaJIT on Windows 10: unknown luaJIT command or jit.*

Tags: windows, lua, luajit

I've been trying to install LuaJIT on Windows 10 for some time following the [official guide](http://luajit.org/), and I actually get to install it. For example, if I execute `luajit` I get into the prompt. Also, `luajit -v` returns the version of luajit (2.0.4). And I can also execute code with `luajit -e <lua code>`. However, whenever I try to save bytecode with `luajit -b`, I get the following message:

*luajit: unknown luaJIT command or jit.* modules not installed*

I tried to make all sort of installations: using [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), [luajit-rocks](https://github.com/torch/luajit-rocks), [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/), ... However, no matter what I try, I always get the same result, and I have no clue of what to do.

Could you point me to some potential problems I might be overlooking?

I have on my system Lua 5.1 and Luarocks.

Comment: Please show the actual command you use that fails. `-b` requires input and output files.

Comment: LuaJIT apparently can't find `jit\bcsave.lua`. Either it's not installed in the correct location, or it's not in `package.path`. Do you maybe overwrite the default `package.path` using the `LUA_PATH` environment variable?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I was overriding the LUA_PATH (and LUA_CPATH) environment variables, and `bcsave.lua` was not in the directory where they were pointing to. I think I did this long time ago, when I first installed Lua and Luarocks, and I'd totally forgotten about it. Thanks so much, you saved my day! Can you post the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some extra LuaJIT features are implemented as separate Lua modules (e.g. `jit.bcsave` for bytecode saving), and LuaJIT depends on `package.path` to find those modules. The suggested install location for those modules is in the default `package.path`, but if you override it via the `LUA_PATH` environment variable, you have to make sure to include that location there. One easy way to do that is to put two consecutive semicolons into `LUA_PATH`: Double semicolons are replaced by the compile-time default value of `package.path`.

Comment: I tried adding the LUA_PATH to the jit modules, but it still cannot find the modules. What can I do?

Comment: @modiX Run `luajit -e "require('jit.bcsave')"`. This should print a list of all the locations LuaJIT looks for `bcsave.lua`. Make sure that the real file location is in there, and fix `LUA_PATH` if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need place modules to "jit" folder near with juajit.exe. That folder include some system modules (bcsave too). package.path can dont work, becouse it hardlinked, how i understand. That folders distributed with source code.
Download lua from official sice: https://luajit.org/download.html
You can see "jit" folder inside archive:
LuaJIT-2.0.5.zip\LuaJIT-2.0.5\src\jit\