# luajit: unknown luaJIT command or jit.* modules not installed

Tags: windows, lua, windows-10, luajit

I'm trying to use the jit module jit.bcsave with luajit. Now this question has been asked here and marked as answer, but the answer did not work for me: [LuaJIT on Windows 10: unknown luaJIT command or jit.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44166483/luajit-on-windows-10-unknown-luajit-command-or-jit)

First of all I followed the install guide [LuaJit's installation guide](http://luajit.org/install.html)

> **Installing LuaJIT** Copy luajit.exe and lua51.dll (built in the src directory) to a newly created directory (any location is ok). Add lua
>   and lua\jit directories below it and copy all Lua files from the
>   src\jit directory of the distribution to the latter directory.
>
> There are no hardcoded absolute path names — all modules are loaded
>   relative to the directory where luajit.exe is installed (see
>   src/luaconf.h).

So my folder structure is:

```
- luajit.exe
- lua51.dll
- lua
  - jit
    - bcsave.lua
```

Still, it won't find my modules.

I also tried adding a `LUA_PATH` environment variable to `.....\lua\jit`, like it's suggested in that answer of the other question. I also tried setting it to `....\lua\jit\?.lua`, but nonetheless it won't work.

My luajit is 2.0 (stable), my OS is Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I also tried adding a LUA_PATH environment variable to .....\lua\jit, like it's suggested in that answer of the other question. I also tried setting it to ....\lua\jit\?.lua, but nonetheless it won't work.

You should add the path as `....\lua\?.lua`, because `jit.bcsave` will be expanded into `....\lua\jit\bcsave.lua`.

The error message lists those paths that have been tried to locate the module, so it can be useful to review those (and include in the question in the future).